# Office365APIs: Querying custom list using Office 365 APIs

Tags: office365

Recently a new preview version of the Office 365 API tools was released. Is it already possible to query custom lists using this API, or only the default types provided such as Calendar and Contacts? The authentication part of it seems to work like a charm, so I think this library has a lot of potential if at some point more content can be made available through it.

http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/

Answer (score 0):

The API can query custom lists.

The SharePoint client object  model SDK is included in this Office 365 API, so you can use the SharePoint client object model to do it. Please refer the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BasicOps_SPListTasks) documentation.

The doc on MSDN is for the version 15 of SharePoint client object model, but the version in Office365 API preview is 16, there might be some difference.